# Does one transaction on Bitcoin require 215 kWh?

Tags: energy, bitcoin

This seems unbelievable:

> This averages out to a shocking 215 kilowatt-hours (KWh) [*sic*] of juice used
>   by miners for each Bitcoin transaction (there are currently about
>   300,000 transactions per day).

Source: [One Bitcoin Transaction Now Uses as Much Energy as Your House in a Week](https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/ywbbpm/bitcoin-mining-electricity-consumption-ethereum-energy-climate-change)

215 kWh is an enormous amount of energy.

Even if mining bitcoins uses a lot of processor power, 215 kWh is still enormous.

Are they confusing all transactions with just mining?

Comment: Finally the question needs work: where does the article say that 215kWh are "required"? Or that the number is anything more than a guesstimate?

Comment: 433 kWh per transaction according to https://digiconomist.net/bitcoin-energy-consumption

Comment: This is most definitely a widely-reported notable claim.  For example, the Wall Street Journal claims 185 kWh per transaction, enough to power 6 households for an entire day.  https://www.wsj.com/articles/bitcoins-wild-ride-shows-the-truth-it-is-probably-worth-zero-1505760623

Comment: This will change over time with the mining complexity and the power efficiency of the hardware used to mine.

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/76149/what-is-the-marginal-energy-cost-of-a-bitcoin-transaction , https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/61883/what-is-the-average-amount-of-electrical-power-required-to-complete-one-bitcoin?rq=1

Comment: "[...] it would be profitable for Bitcoin miners to burn through over 24 terawatt-hours of electricity annually as they compete to solve increasingly difficult cryptographic puzzles to "mine" more Bitcoins." The article, it seems to me, is referring to a *hypothetical* scenario, though it doesn't make this very obvious.

Comment: @Eric, actually, it's independent of efficiency.  As hardware gets more efficient, miners will deploy more of it to get their hash rates up.  To a first-order approximation, cryptocurrency power consumption depends only on electricity costs and currency market prices.