# Does the Bitcoin network consume as much energy as Denmark?

Tags: economics, energy, bitcoin

According to [Ars Technica](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2017/12/bitcoins-insane-energy-consumption-explained/):

> One estimate suggests the Bitcoin network consumes as much energy as Denmark.

There are other sources that make similar claims:

- [Greentech Media](https://www.greentechmedia.com/articles/read/bitcoin-uses-more-energy-than-ireland#gs.YI6Z4hE) claim:

> The [Bitcoin Energy Consumption Index](https://digiconomist.net/bitcoin-energy-consumption) tracker puts Bitcoin’s current estimated annual energy use at almost 32 terawatt-hours, roughly equivalent to Serbia’s yearly electricity consumption and ahead of at least 159 other countries, including Ireland and most nations in Africa.

The [BitCoin Energy Consumption Index](https://digiconomist.net/bitcoin-energy-consumption) is apparently a common source. However, it seems that this article uses a lot of assumptions.

Does the Bitcoin network use about as much energy as Denmark or Ireland, as of late 2017?

Comment: This question is kind of circular. The claim is that the Bitcoin Energy Consumption Index estimates the usage of the Bitcoin network, based on a number of stated assumptions. "Note that one may reach different conclusions on applying different assumptions." What would you accept as confirmation or refutation of this?

Comment: Related: [Does one transaction on Bitcoin require 215 kWh?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/39910).

Comment: A better statement might have been something like *"the Bitcoin network is estimated to consume as much **electricity** as Denmark"* - around 110 PJ each year.  Denmark's **energy consumption** is much higher at around 700-750 PJ a year

Comment: Ideally all electric heaters will run computations one day. ;) Until then, here is an attempt at a more balanced article from a bitcoin follower: https://blog.bitcoin.org.hk/bitcoin-mining-and-energy-consumption-4526d4b56186